# FSMs and Boolean dynamical systems

Tags: finite-automata

Is it not always possible to represent a Finite State Machine (FSM) by a Boolean dynamical system?

A **Boolean dynamical system** is defined by a Boolean map $F\colon B_{0}^n\to B_{0}^n$ (where $B_{0}$ is the-two element Boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$ with operations of $\lor$ (OR), $\land$ (AND) and $\neg$ (NOT)) as

$$x(k+1)=F(x(k)),$$

which is the state update map of the FSM after representing the state space of an FSM as a subset of $B_{0}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, you can represent *any* finite system in this way.

But would you prefer to see my answer written like that, or like this?

```
01011001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100100 01101001 01100100 01101110
00100111 01110100 00100000 01100101 01110110 01100101 01101110 00100000
01101110 01101111 01110100 01101001 01100011 01100101 00100000 01110100
01101000 01100001 01110100 00100000 01110100 01101000 01101001 01110011
00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01100100 01101001 01100110 01100110
01100101 01110010 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 01110100 01100101
01111000 01110100 00101110 00100000 01001111 01101111 01110000 01110011
00101110
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not make it clear, by Boolean map I mean symbolically written state update rule in terms of Boolean functions not as a truth table as you have indicated.

Comment: @VirenSule My point is that any finite system can be represented in binary but that representing it that way often obscures what's really going on and makes it much harder to deal with. The exact details of how it's represented in binary don't make much difference.

Comment: I agree. But instead of state update map written in tables we can write Boolean maps in terms of symbolic Boolean function representation. Then we can utilize Boolean function arithmetic and canonical forms. The representation is computationally advantageous. I wonder why it did not become popular in Computer Science? I thought there are some fundamental issues which dont allow Boolean representation. But if according to you there are none then Boolean representation may offer mathematically richer framework for state machines.

Comment: @VirenSule Use Boolean function arithmetic and canonical forms _to do what_? We're not typically interested in the encoding of the transition function but, rather, in the behaviour of the automaton as a whole. I suggest you try to use your framework to prove that every regular expression describes a language accepted by an NFA, or that every NFA can be translated to a DFA. I bet you a pint of beer that the resulting proofs are much more unpleasant than the conventional proofs of these facts.